# zrangebyscore redis in perl

Tags: perl, redis

I'm using Redis.pm in perl scrpit and try to execute next command:

```
zrevrangebyscore <key> <highscore> 0 WITHSCORES LIMIT 0 1
```

In appliance with redis documentation i write next and it's working fine

```
my $data = { $redis->zrevrangebyscore($rkey, $ipl, 0, 'WITHSCORES') };
```

but when i try to subst 'limit...' in perl command:

```
my $data = { $redis->zrevrangebyscore($rkey, $ipl, 0, 'WITHSCORES','LIMIT 0 1') };
```

i got error

```
[zrevrangebyscore] ERR syntax error,  at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.14/Redis.pm line 163
    Redis::__ANON__(undef, 'ERR syntax error') called at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.14/Redis.pm line 195
    Redis::wait_one_response('Redis=HASH(0x801075300)') called at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.14/Redis.pm line 183
    Redis::wait_all_responses('Redis=HASH(0x801075300)') called at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.14/Redis.pm line 172
```

How i can pass to arg 'LIMIT 0 1' in Redis.pm ?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is:

```
my $data = { $redis->zrevrangebyscore($rkey, $ipl, 0, 'WITHSCORES', qw{LIMIT 0 1})};
```

May be it will be usefull for somebody. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to iterate through your sorted set, and always fetch the highest entry, just use

```
zrange
```

([zrange documentation](http://redis.io/commands/zrange))

instead of zrevrangebyscore.

```
my $start = -1; #-1 is last element = the element with the highest score
my $stop = -1;
while (my $data = $redis->zrange($rkey, $start--, $stop--, 'WITHSCORES')) {
   #fetch the ultimate element, then the penultimate, etc....
};
```